# How to set font in excel using customized data exporter in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, apache-poi

I am using primefaces 6.1. I need to export my report list to excel format.For this i used primefaces data exporter.Dataexporter is giving me excel format. I have also set font in the excel. But the font is not completely working in my excel file.The set font appears in the table header only.
My Code is like this:

```
public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);

    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();  
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.AQUA.index);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    fontHeader.setFontName("Magnus Nepali");
    cellStyle.setFont(fontHeader);
    for(int i=0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++) {
        HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);

        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    }
}
```

My button code is :

```
<p:commandButton id="excel" ajax="false">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tblReport" fileName="report" postProcessor="#{shareDividendMB.postProcessXLS}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

My excel format is like this:[image]

Only excel sheet header has changed  to font defined and the remaining data have Arial font.I tried other than my font and the result is same.

Comment: i didn't understand itext.

Comment: But.. you are only applying the font to the header. Shouldn't you do the same for all cells on all rows?

Comment: Uhhhhh excel vs pdf... Sorry, mixed things up :-( Removed comments (shame on me)

Comment: how can i do that? I think  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle); should have done the job but its not working @JasperdeVries

Comment: @JasperdeVries is right you are only grabbing one row `HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);` you need to loop over ALL the rows in the sheet and set the cell style.

Comment: Thanks @Melloware  for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.My working code is like this:

```
 public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();  
        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.AQUA.index);
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        HSSFFont fontHeader = (HSSFFont) wb.createFont();
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        fontHeader.setFontName("Magnus Nepali");
        cellStyle.setFont(fontHeader);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            }
        }

    }
```